# Setting alias with git bash

Tags: git, git-bash

I've amended my .bash_profile to include :

```
gen='c:\\mydir\\"test dir"\\new'
```

but when I run `"$gen"`

receive error : `sh.exe" cd c:\\mydir\\"test dir"\\new`

The dir exists and running `cd c:\\mydir\\"test dir"\\new` successfully navigates to this dir.

Is alias set correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (works for me):

```
gen='/c/Program Files'
```

Open a new git bash window (so the changes can be loaded):

```
cd "$gen"
```

Comment: @Avalance thanks, that works, for some reason the alias does not work with quotes around dir with spaces, but is required to change dir from git bash

Comment: Yes, very strange. I have been using it for a while on my windows machines, but haven't noticed it. I guess it has something to do with the white spaces, so my advice to you is to avoid them in your file paths :)